# Google Appengine & cloud storage : The AppIdentity service threw an unexpected error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to setup a Google Cloud Storage file upload by following the [sample from google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) with the GcsExampleServlet.java . I've complete all the step but when I deploy the project to aggengine and I try to upload a simple text in GCS , it fail with this log :

```
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.NonRetriableException: com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException: 
The AppIdentity service threw an unexpected error. Details: 
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
at com.appart.storage.server.GcsExampleServlet.doPost(GcsExampleServlet.java:88)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
(...)
```

Still, there is nothing complicate in the code... In web.xml I've configured the servlet :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>GcsExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.example.server.GcsExampleServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>GcsExample</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/gcs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the servlet GcsExampleServlet.java ( exactly the same as in google sample ) :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GcsExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
      .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
      .retryMaxAttempts(10)
      .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
      .build());     
  //...
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
  {
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
    gcsService.createOrReplace(getFileName(req), GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
    copy(req.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
  }

  private void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
      int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
      while (bytesRead != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
      }
    } finally {
      input.close();
      output.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my upload.html file :

```
<form action="/upload.html" enctype="text/plain" method="get" name="putFile" id="putFile">
   <div>
        Bucket: <input type="text" name="bucket" />
        File Name: <input type="text" name="fileName" />
        <br /> File Contents: <br />
        <textarea name="content" id="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" onclick='uploadFile(this)' value="Upload Content" />
   </div>
</form>
<script>

  function uploadFile() {
    var bucket = document.forms["putFile"]["bucket"].value;
    var filename = document.forms["putFile"]["fileName"].value;
    if (bucket == null || bucket == "" || filename == null || filename == "") {
      alert("Both Bucket and FileName are required");
      return false;
    } else {
      var postData = document.forms["putFile"]["content"].value;
      document.getElementById("content").value = null;

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "/gcs/" + bucket + "/" + filename, false);
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
      request.send(postData);
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've enabled Billing, created a bucket but the AppIdentity error still appear. I've no Oauth, the cloud storage API is enabled, the appengine account used to upload has write access to the bucket. I even tried a

```
gsutil acl ch -u warm-particle-718@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:WRITE gs://ctrlxbucket
```

To be sure that the user has write access to my bucket.

Please help me to figure out what this error mean, I'm stick here since days :(

Thanks a lot

PS : If you just have some working sample of GCS ( not the google one ), I'll be happy too since there is not a lot of stuff around that topic.

Comment: I am having similar issue for any AppEngine project created recently to talk to GCS. In python AppEngine code I am getting InternalError that is related to get token code for GCS access. The problem seems to be missing credentials in any new AppEngine app e.g. if you look at Api & auth -> Credentials in Dev Console, it might not have "Compute Engine and AppEngine" client ids for service account. I have a legacy app, created last year, that is working fine though.

Comment: @Abhijit Kalamkar +1. The same for me. I have got my old project which is performing well. But 2 days ago I created new project with the same code and this error occurred. I also noticed that Compute Engine credentials disappeared on new project but I guess this is not case because CtrlX has got 593689673236-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com account mentioned in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102319/google-appengine-cloud-storage-the-appidentity-service-threw-an-unexpected-e#comment40919093_26109439). I guess the solution is in some AppEngine configuration.

Comment: @Juniper Fixed the problem, saw this note on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate Note: In some unusual circumstances, you may not be able to add your service account using the Add member form. If this happens, you must add your app's Service Account Number to the bucket ACL. For more information, see Give permissions to your bucket or objects.

Comment: @AbhijitKalamkar Sound interesting ! I'm trying your solution, but in the doc, when gsutil retrieve the bucket ACL, it seems to be an xml. But I retrieve a JSON. Do you have the same JSON ACL file ?

Comment: @AbhijitKalamkar Actually, it worked  ( with the JSON instead of XML as said in the doc ) ! I have to add {
    "email": "warm-particle-718@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "entity": "user-warm-particle-718@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "role": "WRITER"
  } to the myACL.txt and myDefAcl.txt 
Can you please create an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it ? ( try to give the set provided in the doc for generating the ACL )
Thanks again

Comment: @AbhijitKalamkar In my particular case Service Account Number has already been generated automatically. The error gone for me when I updated my project to AppEngine SDK 1.9.12

Comment: Did this issue get resolved, or is it still occurring? The last activity on this question was in 2014...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of warm-particle-718@appspot.gserviceaccount.com try using XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com (replace XXX with your application's project id - taken
from "Google APIs Console Project Number" in the" Administration/Application Settings" of the admin console).

Comment: This account ( 593689673236-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com )  is already here in the permission and the tooltip says it's for the code running outside the cloud platform. It tried to re-add it but it still don't work :(

Comment: where are you running this code from? a VM engine or a regualr app engine frontend or a backend? If the latter try, 593689673236@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Where did you get the "-compute" part?

Comment: In running all the code directly on appengine, no VM, no localhost. What do you mean by "frontend" or "backend" ? In Permission, I've added 593689673236@developer.gserviceaccount.com but this email need validation and I don't have the access to that mail box.